# Elastic Beanstalk Moded Environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a IIS web application that I want to deploy to a UAT environment as well as a PROD environment. The application has quite a few setting that need to change based on the environment the environment.

What's the best way to set this up so that:

1. When I press F5 / use the local development web server I can select which env I want to emulate.
2. Mark an EC2 environment as UAT or PROD and have it apply a given set of settings easily.

I have read through all the .ebextensions documentation and can't quite find an elegant solution. I must be missing something here.

Comment: "When I press F5" what are you saying here? You want the browser to ask you which environment to emulate every time you reload a page?

Comment: No I'm referring to running your web project from withing Visual Studio.